# "Arrival of Nightfall"

Tags: grammar

Does it make sense to say that something waited until the "arrival of nightfall"? It sounds a little awkward (maybe because nightfall *occurs* rather than *arrives*?). Perhaps there is a better way to say it...

Comment: but then "crack of dawn" would also be incorrect

Comment: @rest_day - "crack of dawn" is such a well-entrenched expression that it would be 'correct' even if it were wrong.

Comment: Same here. This is also a well used expression.

Comment: "Something awaited dusk" or possibly "something awaited twilight"?

Answer (score 4):

"Arrival of" is not necessary at all (*nightfall* means "the beginning of night" so, you'd be saying "the arrival of the beginning of night") and is awkward:

> Something waited until nightfall.

Is the way to express that.

Answer (score 2):

"Fall of night" is an idiom for this time, but waiting for the "arrival of nightfall" (or just "nightfall", as noted by somebody else) isn't wrong.

Comment: When you say that is a common idiom, do you mean in a literary, or a colloquial context? I have never heard "fall of night" in conversation, and all the Google hits seem to be about a Babylon 5 episode.

Comment: @JeffSahol, I've heard it in conversation but from your Google results perhaps my experience is unusual.  I've edited my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably reformulate

> waiting until the arrival of nightfall

as

> waiting until *night falls*

which is somewhat less awkward. But an even simpler way to express this might be

> waiting until sundown

which is cleaner (to my ear, anyway.) The most common way to express the idea is probably

> waiting until evening

at the cost of some specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly in conversational English, you would say 'I waited until it was night time.'

Slightly less commonly, you could say 'I waited for/until nightfall.'